# Generating "artificial" images for training CNN

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I am trying to identify different types of vehicles and logos etc. As with most efforts in this domain the challenge has been a paucity of training images.

Has anyone tried generating artificial images? By "drawing" the logo atop (say) a vehicle hood, vehicle rear and performing distortions (e.g. change color, shape etc.) to give it a more diverse training set.

Are there guidelines and/or best practices in this approach?

Edit: downvoters, at least please comment why you downvoted so I can learn. I am not trying to troll this forum and sincerely asked a question. If you disagree please share your thoughts.

Comment: Data augmentation is a well known technique to address the problem of over fitting. It is advisable that you do so by performing those distortions on the original training images. This could be done by adding noise, performing skew, rotation, cropping random windows and training on those windows. Those are just some examples. Doing this to generated images would not be the best option to try because generated images would not be as good as the available training images.

Comment: @mido - I have done some distortion of training images, are there any papers/samples of types of distortion that provide best results. Thanks for your help

Comment: You can start with this paper http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf It explains the AlexNet and mentions some of the tricks they used which includes some nice data augmentation. Let me know if this answers your question so that I can post it as a solution.

Comment: Yes it does, Thanks @mido. Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data augmentation is a well known technique to address the problem of over fitting. It is advisable that you do so by performing those distortions on the original training images. This could be done by adding noise, performing skew, rotation, cropping random windows and training on those windows. Those are just some examples.

Doing this to generated images would not be the best option to try because generated images would not be as good as the available training images.

Start with this [paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf) It explains the AlexNet and mentions some of the tricks they used which includes some nice data augmentation.